# Transfer pokemons to willow in Pokemon GO

Tags: pokemon-go

Just wanted to ask if I accidentally transferred my Pokemon to Willow, Will I receive candy if I don't have that kind of Pokemon in my collection?

Comment: @lois6b Oh i see thanks for your answer sir, I'm just curious.

Comment: No problem. Welcome to Gaming! Remember to search before asking ;)

Comment: @lois6b Ok sir i will take note to that :)

Answer (score 0):

If its the last Pokemon and you transfer it, you'd still get the candy and be able to use it later on, when you obtain more of this kind of pokemon.